# Binding two different parameter request names to the same controller method parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is it possible to bind two different parameter request names to the same controller method parameter in java spring boot?
Imagine, when a request has been sent to the server like the below:

> Get - /api/test?test1=123

or

> Get - /api/test?test2=123

```
public ResponseEntity<String> test(Long param) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok("test succeeded! param : " + param);

}
```

In both cases, I need to get "test succeeded! param: 123"

I know there is @RequestParam annotation but I accept only one naming alias, I need more than one in my case and I don't want to have more than one parameter for my function.

Do you know if is there any way to do that?

Comment: Inject the `HttpServletRequest` and get it manually. Or write 2 methods which delegate to another method.

Comment: What would your code need to do if someone sends `/api/test?test1=123&test2=456`, or `/api/test` (no query parameters)? I think the best solution is to accept both query parameters, and add some simple code (probably a private method) that takes the two values and returns the right answer. For instance: `return test1 != null ? test1 : test2`